# Does a "Mathematica Stack Exchange Package" exist that collects useful idioms as identified on MSE?

Tags: discussion, packages

I've been browsing MSE for a few weeks now.  Every day, I find a useful snippet from which I learn something new, understand something better, or become aware of just how much I do not know.

It hit me today that while I've seen packages here and there from people like @szabolcs, @Leonid Shifrin,@halirutan, @c.e. and others, I've not seen mention of one or more packages that purports to collect those that are considered "idiomatic" in a cohesive and re-usable manner.

Does such as thing exist anywhere?

Before I get the 'Why do you not create one yourself' answer, please understand that *I am* starting to collect, in a single package, that which I find useful.  Unfortunately though, I have not a depth of experience in similar league to those of whom I spoke previously.  Finally, given my relative inexperience, its difficult to determine if any 'idiom' that I identify is one of quality.  It only, at the least, serves my specific purpose.

If such exists, I would greatly appreciate knowing of it.  I think others would too.

If such doesn't exist, perhaps it might be worth agreeing where and how we might be able to spark the creation of one.

EDIT : 9/16/16 13:55

Packagedata.net is a good resource and I would expect that the package of which I'm speaking would, of course, be referenced there.  And, there are a lot of extremely good articles including the one referenced by @szabolcs in the comment below.  However, what I was looking for is a community supported/guided/approved/managed/etc. package(s) that collect code techniques and idioms that are discussed in that article.

For example, such a package would contain code supporting the Villegas-Gayley trick because that seems to be idiomatic.  Its mentioned in very many posts and, generally, I would rather rely upon code that is proven in more work than just my own.  Additionally, since AFAIK, there are several implementations of the trick, me as a newcomer, cannot judge the best one to leverage.   Having a 'reference' implementation contained within a 'msetools' package relieves me of this concern.

Anyway, it seems to me that such a thing does not actually exist.  So, I suppose i should just answer this question with a resounding 'No' and then ask, of all the examples, which are the ones that should be included in a msetools package.

Comment: I also wish Mathematica's ecosystem of user-written functions and packages was better organized & promoted.  Could you give more detail what you consider to be "idiomatic" though?  Are you thinking of a catch-all repository for useful code, or somehow a more domain-specific organization?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you are asking. This is a collection of packages: http://packagedata.net/  This is a much larger and older collection of all Mathematica-related stuff: http://library.wolfram.com/ But I think you are looking for something more like this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/can-one-identify-the-design-patterns-of-mathematica

Comment: I didn't think Meta.  Frankly, I thought Meta was for talking about MSE administration only.  I'm still a newb.  Be that as it may, I see a reference to an article on Mathematica snippets for MSE yet, if I'm reading that correctly, its not actually come to fruition?

Comment: this question is similar: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79/custom-mathematica-se-function-package

Comment: I agree, they are similar posts.  I disagree with the comments on the other post that frown upon the idea.  The problem is that one has no idea what one needs until they run into a need.  Being able to have a package of  community vetted idiom that point back to the posts will cut down on frustration and lost productivity.  I suppose that there is no reason that it could not be a collection instead of a package either.

Comment: After re-reading the previous article, its appears clear to me that the concerns that such a solution would be undermining the purpose of MSE are not relevant.  I cannot imagine MSE receiving anything other than positive benefits by establishing an MSEPack.

Comment: Related: [Should we have a Github Organization?](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1943/18476)

Comment: Maybe we should have a wiki post (I'm still a little fuzzy on exactly what that is) that brings such things together under the heading of 'Community Sponsored Projects'. I seem to recall that there was a wikibook too.